# How do I get the cells with no dates to have no color until the date is entered? All of the unused cells are red

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, conditional-formatting

```
=DATEDIF(F2,TODAY(),"m")<=47  THE CELL TURNS NO COLOR
=DATEDIF(F2,TODAY(),"m")>57   THE CELL TURNS RED
=DATEDIF(F2,TODAY(),"m")>54   THE CELL TURNS PINK WITH RED WRITING
=DATEDIF(F2,TODAY(),"m")>48   THE CELL TURNS YELLOW
=DATEDIF(F2,TODAY(),"m")>48   THE CELL TURNS GREEN
```

The formulas work, How do I get the cells to have no color until I add the date in f2. Right now the blank cells f2 cells are red and when I add a date the cell turns the right fill color but the date doesn't show up.

Comment: Can you rephrase what the question is?  Or, if I am reading this all right, can you list out all of the questions?  I think the sample formulas are missing a bunch of "D"'s, but I am not sure.  Are all the "DATEIF"'s supposed to be "DATEDIF"'s?  "TOAY()" = "TODAY()"?

Comment: @panhandel I created a spreadsheet that F2 cell will turn green when the persons license is 12 months from expiring. It will turns yellow when the liecense is 6 months from expiring, it turns pink with red fonts when its 3 months from expiring and it turns red 1 month from expiring. But when I do not have a date in f2 the cell fill is red when it should have no fill.

Comment: @panhandel  =DATEIF (F2,TODAY(),"m"<=47  and the fill is clear

Comment: @panhandel I apologize, I keep hitting the return key.  =DATEIF (F2,TODAY(),"m">57 and the fill is red      =DATEIF (F2,TODAY(),"m">54 and the fill is pink      =DATEIF (F2,TODAY(),"m"<=48 and the fill is pink with the date in red      ==DATEIF (F2,TODAY(),"m">48 and the fill is yellow      =DATEIF (F2,TODAY(),"m">=48 and the fill is green.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want your conditional formatting formula to do something like this; essentially wrapping your existing formula inside an IF that checks if F2 is blank.  If it is blank, it returns false (0), if it is not blank, evaluate as you already have it doing it (with some typo corrections)

```
=IF(ISBLANK(F2),0,(DATEDIF(F2,TODAY(),"m")<=47))
```